# SpringBoot Junit bean autowire

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, autowired

I try to write junit test to my service.
I use in my project spring-boot 1.5.1. Everything works fine, but when I try to autowire bean (created in AppConfig.class), it gives me NullPointerException. I've tried almost everything.

This is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration 
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public DozerBeanMapper mapper(){
    DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
    mapper.setCustomFieldMapper(new CustomMapper());
    return mapper;
 }
}
```

and my test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class LottoClientServiceImplTest {
@Mock
SoapServiceBindingStub soapServiceBindingStub;
@Mock
LottoClient lottoClient;
@InjectMocks
LottoClientServiceImpl lottoClientService;
@Autowired
DozerBeanMapper mapper;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    initMocks(this);
    when(lottoClient.soapService()).thenReturn(soapServiceBindingStub);
}

@Test
public void getLastResults() throws Exception {

    RespLastWyniki expected = Fake.generateFakeLastWynikiResponse();
    when(lottoClient.soapService().getLastWyniki(anyString())).thenReturn(expected);

    LastResults actual = lottoClientService.getLastResults();
```

Can someone tells me what's wrong ?

Error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at pl.lotto.service.LottoClientServiceImpl.getLastResults(LottoClientServiceImpl.java:26)
at pl.lotto.service.LottoClientServiceImplTest.getLastResults(LottoClientServiceImplTest.java:45)
```

and this is my service:

```
@Service
public class LottoClientServiceImpl implements LottoClientServiceInterface {
@Autowired
LottoClient lottoClient;
@Autowired
DozerBeanMapper mapper;
@Override
public LastResults getLastResults() {
    try {
        RespLastWyniki wyniki = lottoClient.soapService().getLastWyniki(new Date().toString());
        LastResults result = mapper.map(wyniki, LastResults.class);
        return result;
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw new GettingDataError();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the error log?

Comment: I've just added

Comment: Can you mark line 26 in your code please?

Comment: This is :        LastResults result = mapper.map(wyniki, LastResults.class);
and when i stop there with debugger, mapper is null

Comment: Ofcourse it will be `null`... You are creating an instance yourself and not use the Spring configured one. Replace `@InjectMocks` with `@Autowired` and replace `@Mock` with `@MockBean` and remove your setup method. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Comment: you may find this answer is useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787722/spring-boot-field-injection-with-autowire-not-working-in-junit-test/59409695#59409695

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ofcourse your dependency will be `null`,due to the `@InjectMocks` you are creating a new instance, outside the visibility of Spring and as such nothing will be auto wired.

Spring Boot has extensive testing support and also for replacing beans with mocks, see [the testing section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans) of the Spring Boot reference guide.

To fix it work with the framework instead of around it.

1. Replace `@Mock` with `@MockBean`
2. Replace `@InjectMocks` with `@Autowired`
3. Remove your setup method

Also apparently you only need a mock for the SOAP stub (so not sure what you need to mock for the `LottoClient` for).

Something like this should do the trick.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class LottoClientServiceImplTest {

    @MockBean
    SoapServiceBindingStub soapServiceBindingStub;

    @Autowired
    LottoClientServiceImpl lottoClientService;

    @Test
    public void getLastResults() throws Exception {

        RespLastWyniki expected = Fake.generateFakeLastWynikiResponse();
        when(soapServiceBindingStub.getLastWyniki(anyString())).thenReturn(expected);

        LastResults actual = lottoClientService.getLastResults();
```