# Testing in Spring project - injecting repository into service with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockito

I'm trying to understand how to use **Mockito** in a **Spring** project, but I'm a bit stuck with the following:

I'm about to test a service with a real (in-memory) repository. I'm mocking every other object that's being used by that service. If I understand correctly, annotating an object with `@Mock` will be mocked, `@Spy` will use a real object, and with `@InjectMocks` will kind of "autowire" these annotated objects. However, I think I misunderstood `@Spy` because the following code is not working (seems like a mock object is inserted, neither a DB interaction, neither a `NullPointerException` comes up):

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTests {

    @Spy
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Mock
    private MessageService messageService;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();

    @Test
    public void testUserRegistration() {
        userService.registerUser("test@test.test");

        Assert.assertEquals("There is one user in the repository after the first registration.", 1, userRepository.count());
    }
}
```

If I remove the *@Spy* annotation and insert the repository in the service with reflection, it works:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(userService, "userRepository", userRepository);
```

This seems inconvenient, and I'm pretty sure that `@Spy` is meant to do this. Can anyone point out what I'm missing/misunderstanding?

*Edit:* one more thing - with the `@Spy` annotation I'm not getting a `NullPointerException` on save, but it seems like a mock object is inserted instead of the real repository.

*Edit 2:* I think this is the answer for my confusion:

[SpringBoot Junit bean autowire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099556/springboot-junit-bean-autowire?rq=1)

Comment: Why do you have Autowired *and* Spy? Could you expand on *"not working"*?

Comment: Pretty sure you should be using `@Mock` above your repository

Comment: If at all practical, it's better to use constructor injection for precisely this reason--you don't need Spring for this test and can simply create and pass a mock to `new UserServiceImpl(mockUserRepository)`.

Comment: @chrylis this would mean that I have to modify all the services, because field injection is used everywhere, and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @ThomasWithers I'm trying to use an in-memory db for testing, Mock wouldn't do what I want, would it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe based on your question I'm clearly using it wrong, I just don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you probably `@Autowired` some services/repositories in `UserService` like these:

```
public class UserServiceImpl() {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;
  @Autowired
  private MessageService messageService;

  // ... all the stuff
}
```

Mockito tries to inject mocks through constructor or setters which are not available. Try to redesign your class `UserServiceImpl`, so it has constructor like:

```
public class UserServiceImpl() {

  private final UserRepository userRepository;
  private final MessageService messageService;

  @Autowired
  public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, MessageService messageService) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.messageService = messageService;
  }
```

Then you can instantiate the service in `@Before` with the constructor using those mocks.

Comment: So the `@Spy` and `@Autowired` annotations on the repository in the test are correct by the way, my only problem is the field autowiring?

Comment: If you setup in-memory database in test context in the configuration, then I don't see a reason to use @Spy on the repository, since it is already a mock of real database. 
And yes I think that the only problem with that is field autowiring instead of constructor/setter. Also I'll highly recommend to use constructor injections.

Comment: Also, now I see that you are missing `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in `@Before`

Comment: I actually missed the existence of `@MockBean` annotation and basically I wanted to do it manually by combining some. :)

Comment: Also if I try to exclude the Spring parts from the test as much as I can and use MockitoJUnitRunner instead of SpringRunner I won't need to watch out for these if I'm correct.